# Как сделать поиск по вложенному объекту в MongoDB почему возвращается пустой массив?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Приветствую) Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так?
Как сделать поиск в MongoDB, **по вложенному объекту???**
Надо сделать поиск по полям (login, password)....
Они находятся **во вложенном объекте (user)**.
Почему возвращается **пустой массив**?

#### DB

```js
{
 _id: ObjectId("5f4d31dc5e7b610a0c7914d2")
 user: {
        login:  "qwerty",
        password:  "123"
    }
 jwt: "qwerty#5f4d31dc5e7b610a0c7914d2"
 __V: 0
}
```

#### userSchema.js

```js
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        login: String,
        password: String
    },
    jwt: String
});
```

Если в **DB** нет вложенного объекта, то всё работает... Но мне нужно сделать с вложенным

#### api.js

```js
router.post('/users/user/:login', (req,res) => {
   User.find({login: req.body.login, password: req.body.password})
   .then((data) => {
       console.log(data);
    })
});
```

Comment: `User.find({'user.login': req.body.login, 'user.password': req.body.password})`

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что надо искать так:

```
User.find({
  user: {
    login: req.body.login,
    password: req.body.password,
  }
})
```

PS: Прокомментируйте кто-нибудь, да или нет - если нет, удалю.